# how to replace second match character OR string from string using PHP?

Tags: php, regex

### how to replace second match character OR string from string using PHP?

INPUT : example.com?q=123123?name=shreyas&city=surat#anchor1

OUTPUT : example.com?q=123123?name=shreyas&city=surat#anchor1

Comment: Does `str_replace($find, $replace, $string);` not work?

Comment: second match character ??

Comment: @ShreyasPatel: How do you get that string in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $first = strpos($url , '?'); // find first occurance
 $str = substr($url , 0 ,$first+1); remove first part 
 preg_replace('/\sis\s/i', 'XXX' , $str);
```

Comment: this is my string

http://www.example.com?q=123123?name=shreyas&city=surat#anchor1

and 

output should be something like

http://www.example.com?q=123123&name=shreyas&city=surat#anchor1

Comment: yes exactly the same output I need

Answer (score -1):

To avoid to match "is" inside another word, you can use a word boundary `\b`:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\bis\b/i' , 'xxx', $str);
```

Comment: this is my string

http://www.example.com?q=123123?name=shreyas&city=surat#anchor1

and 

output should be something like

http://www.example.com?q=123123&name=shreyas&city=surat#anchor1

Comment: @ShreyasPatel: In this case, you must edit your question to explain **clearly** what you want to do, with examples and with what you have tried.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$result = preg_replace('/\bis\b/i' , 'xxx', $str);

?>
```

[Demo!](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?374ii)

And for your second question:

```
<?php

$result = preg_replace('/(?<!com)\?/' , '&', $url); 

?>
```

Note: Use & instead of & if you want to display the result to users.

Comment: this is my string

http://www.example.com?q=123123?name=shreyas&city=surat#anchor1

and 

output should be something like

http://www.example.com?q=123123&name=shreyas&city=surat#anchor1

Comment: `$result = preg_replace('/(?<!com)\?/' , '&', $url);` Use `&amp;` instead of `&` if you want to display the result to users.